# Auto reload new images in feh image viewer

Tags: raspbian, linux, display, kiosk

I am making a project about wireless notice board using an android app and a raspberry pi. I am using feh image viewer to display images as slideshow from a specific folder.

The command I am using:

```
/usr/bin/feh --quiet --recursive --randomize --full-screen --slideshow-delay 7 /home/pi/New
```

It's displaying properly but has one problem. If I add a new image in the folder it won't display until it is restarted. Can somebody tell any method in which I can to auto reload as soon as something is added? Or is there any other image viewer which is capable of performing the required task?

Answer (score 2):

According to [feh's documentation](http://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/), the solution is fairly simple.  If you add the parameter `-R n` (where n is an integer), it will automatically reload from the specified directory every n seconds.

Comment: I tried this but its not working in my case . I have found another image viewer called Eye of GNOME .This is doing my work perfectly .Its slideshow automatically shows the new added image without adding anything in command line.

Comment: ...while also resetting the zoom settings every `n` seconds ; Try `feh -R 5 --scale-down <your-img>`

Answer (score 1):

In my project I upload photos from webcams, so I need to refresh also. Only feh did the job. I first tried with eog but had problems with display timeout: even if I put BLANK_TIME and POWERDOWN_TIME to zero in /etc/kbd/config, in the middle of the night the video ignored those parameters and became blank. This didn't happen with feh.

```
feh -Z -F -R 5 -Y /home/pi/photos
```

Answer (score 1):

Given directory `$d` where new images are being created, for displaying the images as they appear, starting from the freshest one, I'm using

```
feh -S mtime --reverse -D 1 -R 1 --on-last-slide hold --start-at $(ls -1tr "$d" | tail -n 1) "$d"
```

(I'm not sure how it performs for huge amount of images, as it is short-periodically reloading the list)

Options used:

- `-S mtime` sorts images by their modification (creation) time
- `--reverse` reverses the sort order (as default is descending, for some reason)
- `-D 1` slideshow delay 1 sec
- `-R 1` regenerates image list every 1 sec
- `--on-last-slide hold` to stop on last image, not quit or restart
- `--start-at $(ls -1tr "$d" | tail -n 1)` starts the slideshow with the newest one

Comment: I think this answer answers the question best. I shows an image which got added to a folder with a different filename. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
 --auto-reload
             (optional feature, enabled in this build) automatically reload image when the underlying file changes.  Note that auto-reload (if enabled in the build) is on by default.  This option is only useful to re-enable auto-
             reload after it has been disabled by a preceding --reload=0 option.
```

Comment: Note that this does not reload entire filelists in case you have opened an directory in feh and added more images to that directory afterwards.